# how to use Azure b2c Authentication on front-side with angular

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-b2c

so I want to enable Azure b2c authentication only on front side.
my front-side is on
http://localhost:4200 (Angular)
my back-end is on
http://localhost:3000 (Node + Express)

I want that before someone will land on http://localhost:4200/index
he Will have to be authenticated with azure b2c (signup & login through google/email).
so there is no need with deployment on back-end.

how can I do so.

I have azure account and already created AD B2C profile.

thanks for any helping here.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the angular samples here: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/apps/tree/master/apps